# Given a list of random hexadecimal colors, sort them based on "likeness"

Tags: javascript, sorting, colors, grouping, approximation

For example, this list of hexadecimal values:

```
{
"colors" : [{"hex"   : "#fe4670"},
            {"hex"   : "#5641bc"},
            {"hex"   : "#d53fc3"},
            {"hex"   : "#6b5e09"},
            {"hex"   : "#4dd685"},
            {"hex"   : "#88d63f"},
            {"hex"   : "#eb93f3"},
            {"hex"   : "#f44847"},
            {"hex"   : "#32d159"},
            {"hex"   : "#6e9bde"},
            {"hex"   : "#c3ec64"},
            {"hex"   : "#81cce5"},
            {"hex"   : "#7233b6"},
            {"hex"   : "#bb90c3"},
            {"hex"   : "#728fde"},
            {"hex"   : "#7ef46a"},
            {"hex"   : "#f7cfff"},
            {"hex"   : "#c8b708"},
            {"hex"   : "#b45a35"},
            {"hex"   : "#589279"},
            {"hex"   : "#51f1e1"},
            {"hex"   : "#b1d770"},
            {"hex"   : "#db463d"},
            {"hex"   : "#5b02a2"},
            {"hex"   : "#909440"},
            {"hex"   : "#6f53fe"},
            {"hex"   : "#4c29bd"},
            {"hex"   : "#3b24f8"},
            {"hex"   : "#465271"},
            {"hex"   : "#6243"},
            {"hex"   : "#dbcc4"},
            {"hex"   : "#187c6"},            
            {"hex"   : "#1085e2"},
            {"hex"   : "#b521e9"},
            {"hex"   : "#4bd36d"},             
            {"hex"   : "#11bc34"},
            {"hex"   : "#455c47"},
            {"hex"   : "#a71bbf"},
            {"hex"   : "#988fc2"},
            {"hex"   : "#226cfe"}]
}
```

Ideally it should group "greens", "blues", "purples", etc.

I've yet to come up with a good way to group them. Converting the colors to HSV and then sorting by Hue, then Sat then Val works almost fine, but there are a few exceptions that stand out:

[image]

Another method I've read about is converting them to a LAB color space and then calculating the DeltaE. I've had mixed success with this:

[image]

(this is sorting the whole list against one color). I'd like to sort the distance of every color against every color.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference just to mention (I guess you already read the article)

Answer (score 1):

The following example selects the first color for use as a comparison color. It first adds that color to a new array, then iterates through the rest of the colors comparing the colors looking for the most similar color.

For each color it iterates, it subtracts the red from the second color in the comparison from that of the first, then the green, then the blue. It then finds the absolute values (no negative numbers). After that it adds those values together and divides by three. This number is the average difference between the two colors.

Once it finds the closest color, it selects that color as the new comparison color, removes it from the original array of colors, and pushes it into the sorted array. It does this until there are no colors left.

It definitely needs some work as can be seen when supplied with a larger data set, but it is all I had time for last night. I will continue to work on this until I have something better.

```js
const sort = data => {
    data = Object.assign([], data);
    const sorted = [data.shift()];

    while(data.length) {
        const [a] = sorted, c = { d: Infinity };

        for(let [i, b] of Object.entries(data)) {
            const average = Math.floor((
                Math.abs(a.r - b.r) +
                Math.abs(a.g - b.g) +
                Math.abs(a.b - b.b)
            ) / 3);

            if(average < c.d) {
                Object.assign(c, { d: average, i: i });
            }
        }
        
        sorted.unshift(data.splice(c.i, 1)[0]);
    }
    
    return sorted.reverse();
};

const test = (title, data) => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h2>${title}</h2>`);

    for(let c of data) {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<swatch style="background: rgb(${c.r},${c.g},${c.b})"></swatch>`);
    }
    
    return test;
}

const data = [
    {"hex": "#fe4670"},{"hex": "#5641bc"},{"hex": "#d53fc3"},{"hex": "#6b5e09"},
    {"hex": "#4dd685"},{"hex": "#88d63f"},{"hex": "#eb93f3"},{"hex": "#f44847"},
    {"hex": "#32d159"},{"hex": "#6e9bde"},{"hex": "#c3ec64"},{"hex": "#81cce5"},
    {"hex": "#7233b6"},{"hex": "#bb90c3"},{"hex": "#728fde"},{"hex": "#7ef46a"},
    {"hex": "#f7cfff"},{"hex": "#c8b708"},{"hex": "#b45a35"},{"hex": "#589279"},
    {"hex": "#51f1e1"},{"hex": "#b1d770"},{"hex": "#db463d"},{"hex": "#5b02a2"},
    {"hex": "#909440"},{"hex": "#6f53fe"},{"hex": "#4c29bd"},{"hex": "#3b24f8"},
    {"hex": "#465271"},{"hex": "#6243"},  {"hex": "#dbcc4"}, {"hex": "#187c6"},
    {"hex": "#1085e2"},{"hex": "#b521e9"},{"hex": "#4bd36d"},{"hex": "#11bc34"},
    {"hex": "#455c47"},{"hex": "#a71bbf"},{"hex": "#988fc2"},{"hex": "#226cfe"}
].reduce((m, e) => (m.push(Object.assign(e, {
    r: parseInt(e.hex.substring(1, 3), 16) || 0,
    g: parseInt(e.hex.substring(3, 5), 16) || 0,
    b: parseInt(e.hex.substring(5, 7), 16) || 0
})), m), []);

const bigdata = (() => {
    const data = [];

    const rand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    for(let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        data.push({r: rand(), g: rand(), b: rand()});
    }
    
    return data;
})();

test('Unsorted', data)('Sorted', sort(data))('A Larger Dataset', sort(bigdata));
```

```css
swatch { display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid;  margin-left: 1px; margin-top: 1px; width: 20px; height: 20px; }
h2 { margin: 0; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, "Sans Serif"}
```

The following snippet does mostly the same thing, except that it searches the sorted array to find the closest match in that array, then inserts the color from the unsorted array next to its closest match.

It doesn't seem to do as good of a job gradienting the swatches, but it does seem to group the colors together better.

```js
const sort = data => {
    data = Object.assign([], data);
    const sorted = [data.shift()];

    while(data.length) {
        const a = data.shift(), c = { d: Infinity };

        for(let [i, b] of Object.entries(sorted)) {
            const average = Math.floor((
                Math.abs(a.r - b.r) +
                Math.abs(a.g - b.g) +
                Math.abs(a.b - b.b)
            ) / 3);

            if(average < c.d) {
                Object.assign(c, { d: average, i: i });
            }
        }
        
        sorted.splice(c.i, 0, a);
    }
    
    return sorted.reverse();
};

const test = (title, data) => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h2>${title}</h2>`);

    for(let c of data) {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<swatch style="background: rgb(${c.r},${c.g},${c.b})"></swatch>`);
    }
    
    return test;
}

const data = [
    {"hex": "#fe4670"},{"hex": "#5641bc"},{"hex": "#d53fc3"},{"hex": "#6b5e09"},
    {"hex": "#4dd685"},{"hex": "#88d63f"},{"hex": "#eb93f3"},{"hex": "#f44847"},
    {"hex": "#32d159"},{"hex": "#6e9bde"},{"hex": "#c3ec64"},{"hex": "#81cce5"},
    {"hex": "#7233b6"},{"hex": "#bb90c3"},{"hex": "#728fde"},{"hex": "#7ef46a"},
    {"hex": "#f7cfff"},{"hex": "#c8b708"},{"hex": "#b45a35"},{"hex": "#589279"},
    {"hex": "#51f1e1"},{"hex": "#b1d770"},{"hex": "#db463d"},{"hex": "#5b02a2"},
    {"hex": "#909440"},{"hex": "#6f53fe"},{"hex": "#4c29bd"},{"hex": "#3b24f8"},
    {"hex": "#465271"},{"hex": "#6243"},  {"hex": "#dbcc4"}, {"hex": "#187c6"},
    {"hex": "#1085e2"},{"hex": "#b521e9"},{"hex": "#4bd36d"},{"hex": "#11bc34"},
    {"hex": "#455c47"},{"hex": "#a71bbf"},{"hex": "#988fc2"},{"hex": "#226cfe"}
].reduce((m, e) => (m.push(Object.assign(e, {
    r: parseInt(e.hex.substring(1, 3), 16) || 0,
    g: parseInt(e.hex.substring(3, 5), 16) || 0,
    b: parseInt(e.hex.substring(5, 7), 16) || 0
})), m), []);

const bigdata = (() => {
    const data = [];

    const rand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    for(let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        data.push({r: rand(), g: rand(), b: rand()});
    }
    
    return data;
})();

test('Unsorted', data)('Sorted', sort(data))('A Larger Dataset', sort(bigdata));
```

```css
swatch { display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid;  margin-left: 1px; margin-top: 1px; width: 20px; height: 20px; }
h2 { margin: 0; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, "Sans Serif"}
```